# Email is not displayed in the List?

Tags: android

The code I am using will display the **Name and Number** in the listview, but I need to display the Email also, for that I added some code snippet but Email didn't display in the listview. I am using Android 2.1 platform.

**CODE**

```
 public class Trial2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

            } 
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (reqCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                Cursor Emails = null;
                String number = "";
                String mailid;
                try {

                    Uri result = data.getData();

                    //get the id from the uri
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  

                    //query
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? " , new String[] {id}, null);


                    int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);  

                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);

                    } else {

                    }

                     Emails = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);

                     int emailid = Emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

                     if(Emails.moveToFirst()){

                         mailid =Emails.getString(emailid);
                     }else {

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //failed 
                } finally {
                    if (cursor!=null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Trial2" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Solution ? Please.

Comment: Where is your listView?? did you post entire source code?

Comment: @BigBoss : The code you've posted doesn't have any reference to a `ListView` or an `Adapter` to populate it. If you want an answer to your question, you need to post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet to display your Email in listview.This will be helpful

```
Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                       null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                       + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null); 

while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 

String email = emailCur.getString(
              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
String emailType = emailCur.getString(
              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 
}     emailCur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for getting email

```
Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                           null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                           + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null); 
    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
    // This would allow you get several email addresses
        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
    String email = emailCur.getString(
                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 
} 
emailCur.close();
```

after getting values of gmail id you have to pass those values into listview , in your code there is no listview in the activity check that once......

Comment: No change ,I got only the name and number in listview after using this code .

Comment: how you are adding those values to list view , are you getting emails in the at least in log

Comment: No.Actually ListView is not needed to display the datas,it will automatically display Name and number in the activity when we press that single button.i am trying to add the email along with the name and number.you got it ?

Comment: are you able to getting emails in log. do debug and check those are coming or not

Comment: No display in Logcat. Is any other ways

Comment: above code working for me getting email. check this tutorial--http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/

Comment: You get the output. Great i will check